# Server 16.04.02 Installation Issues with a Dell PE T20

Tags: 16.04, server, partitioning, system-installation

Finally got Ubuntu 16.04.02 installed on a Dell PE T20 last night. (Legacy, ATA)

However, I had to do it without RAID on the install. I am willing to take any suggestions and attempt to install to the RAID versus creating the RAID after a single disk install.

Things I have tried :

1. UEFI Enabled w/ AHCI

   - w/ ATA
   - w/ RAID Enabled
2. Legacy Enabled w/ AHCI

   - w/ ATA
   - w/ RAID enabled

All six of these options produce the same result when I did a custom partition of:

ESP - if needed - , /boot, /,/swap

The partitioner would say that I have the partions. I would go to commit to disk, then I would get an error saying a partition is in use. I would go to a terminal and find that one of the swap partitions was mounted. I would have to do a mdadm -force -stop /dev/mdxxx to get it to release. At which point I would restart the disk partioning process. Ubuntu installer would say it completes, and then I would reboot to a "No Operating System found"

Any thoughts on what is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, there are three types of RAID:

- **Hardware RAID** -- This type of RAID is implemented in firmware on the disk controller, and is common on server computers. Your Dell T20 is officially a server computer, so it might have a hardware RAID controller; but that's not 100% certain. When using this form of RAID, all the RAIDed devices look like a single hard disk (`/dev/sda`, typically) to Ubuntu, and no special in-OS configuration is required.
- **Motherboard-based software RAID** -- This is a type of RAID that relies on drivers in the OS, but its standards are defined by the motherboard manufacturer, and there's also minimal support in the firmware. This is good for using RAID on a dual-booting computer, but I do *not* recommend using it on a Linux-only installation. This type of RAID is sometimes called "fake RAID," but that's a somewhat misleading term; it's RAID, just not hardware RAID. In Ubuntu, this type of RAID is managed with the `dmraid` tool.
- **Linux software RAID** -- This is another type of software RAID, but instead of a manufacturer-defined standard, it relies on standards defined by Linux developers. As such, it's better for a Linux-only installation (including a dual-boot between Ubuntu and another Linux distribution). This type of RAID is managed in Ubuntu with the `mdadm` tool.

You appear to be trying to use motherboard-based software RAID, which IMHO is the worst type of RAID to use. I recommend you abandon that attempt. Instead, try to ascertain if your computer supports true hardware RAID. If it does, use that; it will be simpler in terms of Ubuntu's configuration and, depending on the RAID level, is likely to impose less CPU overhead.

If your computer does not support hardware RAID, I recommend you *disable* the RAID features in your firmware setup utility and instead use Linux software RAID. That's likely to be less troublesome. Of course, if you're dual-booting (which would be odd on a server), using motherboard-based software RAID may be your only choice.

In any of these cases, I know of no easy to convert from a non-RAID to a RAID configuration; you'll need to re-install (or back up and restore your current installation).

See the [Ubuntu software RAID wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID) for more on setting up that type of RAID, or the [fake RAID HOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto) if you decide to use that approach. Hardware RAID requires no special Ubuntu configuration; but it must be set up using manufacturer-provided tools similar to the firmware setup utility. You should read the manufacturer's documentation or watch carefully as the computer boots for hints about how to enter the RAID configuration tool.